# Springboot Mybatis Transaction Rollback doesn't work

Tags: transactions, mybatis, rollback

I'm using Mybatis Transaction Servcie

```
 @Bean(name="sqlSession", destroyMethod="clearCache")
    public SqlSession sqlSession() throws Exception{
        //SqlSessionTemplate sessionTemplate = new SqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory());
        SqlSessionTemplate sessionTemplate = new SqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory(),ExecutorType.BATCH);
        return sessionTemplate;
    }
```

```
  @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
        transactionManager.setGlobalRollbackOnParticipationFailure(false);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

There are my Transaction setting.

```
@Transactional
    public void bulkInsert(int raffleNo, List<RaffleData> raffleDataList) throws DataAccessException {

        SqlSession batchSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH,false);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try{
            //batchSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH,false);
            batchSession.insert("raffle.insertBulkRaffleData", raffleDataList);
            batchSession.commit();
        }catch(Throwable throwable){
            logger.error("Throwable ..... ");
            batchSession.rollback();
            throw new PersistenceException(throwable);
        }
        finally{
            batchSession.flushStatements();
            batchSession.close();
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.error("Bulk Insert Time : " + (endTime-startTime)/1000 + "(ms)");
    }
```

but Rollback Service does not work... I don't know reason
I'm using mariadb and innodb Engine

Comment: If you use `@Transactional`, you should not call `commit()` or `rollback()` in your code (see mybatis-spring [documentation](http://mybatis.org/spring/transactions.html)). This [example](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/cockroachdemo/service/MyBatisAccountService.java#L52) shows you a typical service implementation.

Comment: Thank for your help ave